# How to make afro (solid)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, 3d-printing

[image]

I want to make an afro like in the picture. Unlike the ones you can see the fine strands of hair since this will be 3d printed. Is there a nice way to do it that isn’t sculpting mode and grabbing at every bump? Thank you.

Comment: You can use a displacement modifier with a clouds texture. If you need help with how to do that reply and I'll walk you through it.

Comment: @NascentSpace Yes please. I have no experience with the displacement modifier and would love if you could walk me through it.

Comment: Make sure you have selected the hair object, and then go to the modifiers tab on the right side of the screen. Then click add a modifier and find the displacement modifier and click it. Then make sure to add a new texture and press the tiny wrench button to edit the texture. There you can change the texture type to clouds and change the size as well.